# How do I get functional graphics from freepascal?

Tags: graphics, freepascal

I've been all over the documentation, and there's nothing comprehensive on the subject of graphics. I know it's possible; I've seen freepascal projects that include functional graphics, but haven't been able to replicate the effect myself.

The basics will be sufficient; lines, polygons, possibly text. Any features beyond that (png support, gradients, resizable window, etc) would be appreciated, but unnecessary. The purpose of this question is to find a workable, testable starting point, not to pick out the best libraries for a given purpose.

If it helps, I'm using Lazarus and I have some experience with Pascal as a whole, but I've been away from it since 2007.

Comment: Which library to use depends on what you are trying to achieve. However, library recommendation questions are off topic here.

Comment: Honestly, I'd settle for just about anything. I haven't been able to find a foothold anywhere, and so just having a starting point would be useful.

Comment: Starting point. You tell us what you want to draw. The more you put in to the questions here, the more reward you will get.

Comment: Edited. I'm mostly just looking for the basics. Nothing more complicated than what you'd do with a pencil.

Comment: Add a TPaintBox. Handle its OnPaint event. Draw using the Canvas property of the paint box, with code inside the OnPaint event handler.

Answer (score 2):

simple graphics starting point

- Canvas Drawing: https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Drawing_with_canvas
- Using BGRA (open source drawing lib): https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/BGRABitmap
- Library list (not complete but a good start):) https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Graphics_libraries

Also, I'd like to point out that a lot can be found by searching the fpc wiki, or by visiting the forums,
Here's the "Graphics" forum board,
https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/board,39.0.html